# Range with skipped value

Tags: bash

Can I do this with one bash for statement?  I have a range {1..8} but I want to take out 4.  I know I can do this with two for statements:

```
for i in {1..3} blah blah blah
for i in {5..8} blah blah blah
```

I know I can add an if statement in the for loop.  But was wondering if I could possibly use a short regex?

Comment: If the objection to an `if` statement is that it takes 3 lines, you can do `[ $i -eq 4 ] && continue` in just one line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you want but we can simply say:

```
for i in {1..3} {5..8}; do
    echo $i
    # or do whatever you like ..
done
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well from the question I can't really make out whether you wish to divide them in half (1...4 and 5...8) or split them into odds and evens (1,3,5,7 on one side and the rest in the other).

In the first case you could do a loop through the whole thing and ask if( i < 5 ) whereas in the second one, you could check if( i % 2 == 0 ).
Hope that helped!

Comment: I did say I knew I could use an if statement in there.  and this is what I need. i=1,2,3,5,6,7,8.  I thought this was pretty clear but I guess not.